# How can I use different sets of date values depending on the date

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am looking to automate a daily report for my company but I have run in to a bit of trouble. The report gets updated only on the 2nd working day of each month. I found some code on the SAS website which works out what the 2nd working day of any month is.

```
data scdwrk;
  /* advance date to the first day of the month using the INTNX function */
  second=intnx('month',today(),0);
  /* determine the day of the week using the WEEKDAY function */
  day=weekday(second);
  /* if day=Monday then advance by 1 */
  if day=2 then second+1;
  /* if day=Sunday then advance by 2 */
  else if day=1 then second+2;
  format second date9.;
run ;
```

I have also set a flag that compares todays date to the date from this generated by this piece of code. 
I now need to find a way that if the code is run on the first working day of the month then it runs a particular set of macro date variables

```
%let start_date="&prevmnth;
%let end_date= &endprevmnth;
%let month= &prevyearmnth;
```

and then when its run on the 2nd working day of the month it uses the other set of macro date variables (calender month)

```
%let start_date="&currmnth;
%let end_date= &endcurrmnth;
%let month= &curryearmnth;
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if the 1st of the month is a Saturday?  Or if it's a holiday?  (Is "second working day" really "first tuesday", intended to be the second OR first depending on if it's a holiday, except for holidays like 12/25 or 7/4 that don't move around...)?

Comment: Hi joe, thanks for the reply. The company are willing to do it manually should bank holidays and such arise but in the field we are in its very rare that will those holidays will effect us.

Comment: Rereading this I can't figure out what the question is, exactly.  You've got some code that works (it's not exactly what I'd use but it seems good enough).  What's the question?  Are you asking how to make macro variables from a data step?

Comment: The question I guess is hot to switch from using one set of date values in the code to another set of date values automatically.
Take June for example. On the 1st of June I need the program to run with the dates from May as as Maysa data is still being used, so I set macro variables to contain the previous months date (which is now May). 
Come the 2nd of June (the 2nd working day) the program needs to switch to June data so its need to run with the current month macro variables that have been created instead of the previos months.
I would to find a way to automate that process.

Answer (score 1):

I have some recent code that does just this.  Here is how I tackled it.

First, create a table of holidays.  This can be maintained yearly.

Second, create a table with the first 5 days of the month that are not weekend days.

Third, delete holidays.

Finally, get the second value in the data set.

```
data holidays;
format holiday_date date9.;
informat holiday_date date9.;
input holiday_date;
datalines;
01JAN2015
19JAn2015
16FEB2015
03APR2015
25MAY2015
03JUL2015
07SEP2015
26NOV2015
25DEC2015
;

data _dates;
firstday = intnx('month',today(),0);
format firstday date date9.;
do date=firstday to firstday+5;
    if 1 < weekday(date) < 7 then
        output;
end;
run;

proc sql noprint;
delete from _dates
where date in (select holiday_date from holidays);

quit;

data _null_;
set _dates(firstobs=2);
call symput("secondWorkDay",put(date,date9.));
stop;
run;

%put &secondWorkDay;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. its definitely better than the version on the SAS page.